# Reading from txt file into a linked list

Tags: c++, linked-list

I am attempting to read data from a *.txt file into a linked list. The file is set up with 16 different types of data arranged into rows, with tabs between each data type. I am having several problems with this. The compiler gives no errors, but when I run the program and enter the file name to be read from, nothing happens. I tried replacing the `while(!din.eof())` line (line 27 below) with a for loop `for(int i=0; i<NUM_LINES; i++)`, and this seemed to help, but I was given the first three elements (all string types) followed by a row of zeroes, with this line repeating until the end of the loop. I've included the method in which I believe the problem is located below. I was wondering if someone could take a look at my code and let me know where the problem is. Thanks.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

class Node
{
 public:
   // Constructors
   Node();
   Node(const string name, const string position, const string team, const int g, const int att, const float attg, const int cmp, const float pct, const int yds, const float ydsg, const int lng, const int td, const int inte, const int sck, const int sckyl, const float rating);
   Node(const Node & node);
   ~Node();

   // Methods
   bool readData();
   void setNext(Node* next);
   void print() const;

 private:
   string Name;
   string Position;
   string Team;
   int G;
   int Att;
   float AttG;
   int Cmp;
   float Pct;
   int Yds;
   float YdsG;
   int Lng;
   int TD;
   int Int;
   int Sck;
   int SckYL;
   float Rating;
   Node *Next;
};

//----------------------------------------------
// Constructor method
//----------------------------------------------
Node::Node()
{
   Name = "";
   Position = "";
   Team = "";
   G = 0;
   Att = 0;
   AttG = 0.0;
   Cmp = 0;
   Pct = 0.0;
   Yds = 0;
   YdsG = 0.0;
   Lng = 0;
   TD = 0;
   Int = 0;
   Sck = 0;
   SckYL = 0;
   Rating = 0.0;
   Next = NULL;
}

//----------------------------------------------
// Constructor method with parameters
//----------------------------------------------
Node::Node(const string name, const string position, const string team, const int g, const int att, const float attg, const int cmp, const float pct, const int yds, const float ydsg, const int lng, const int td, const int inte, const int sck, const int sckyl, const float rating)
{
   Name = name;
   Position = position;
   Team = team;
   G = g;
   Att = att;
   AttG = attg;
   Cmp = cmp;
   Pct = pct;
   Yds = yds;
   YdsG = ydsg;
   Lng = lng;
   TD = td;
   Int = inte;
   Sck = sck;
   SckYL = sckyl;
   Rating = rating;
   Next = NULL;
}

//----------------------------------------------
// Copy constructor method
//----------------------------------------------
Node::Node(const Node & node)
{
   Name = node.Name;
   Position = node.Position;
   Team = node.Team;
   G = node.G;
   Att = node.Att;
   AttG = node.AttG;
   Cmp = node.Cmp;
   Pct = node.Pct;
   Yds = node.Yds;
   YdsG = node.YdsG;
   Lng = node.Lng;
   TD = node.TD;
   Int = node.Int;
   Sck = node.Sck;
   SckYL = node.SckYL;
   Rating = node.Rating;
   Next = NULL;
}

//----------------------------------------------
// Destructor method
//----------------------------------------------
Node::~Node()
{
}

//----------------------------------------------
// Method:   readData
// Purpose:  Read data from file into linked list, and print contents of the list.
//----------------------------------------------
bool Node::readData()
{
   // Declare local variables
   string name, position, team;
      name = position = team = "";
   int g, att, cmp, yds, lng, td, inte, sck, sckyl;
      g = att = cmp = yds = lng = td = inte = sck = sckyl = 0;
   float attg, pct, ydsg, rating;
      attg = pct = ydsg = rating = 0.0;

   // Get file name
   string filename = "";
   cout << "Enter file name: ";
   cin >> filename;

   // Open input file
   ifstream din;
   din.open(filename.c_str());
   if (din.fail())
   {
      cerr << "Could not open file: " << filename << endl;
      return false;
   }

   // Read data
   Node *head = NULL;
   while (!din.eof())
   {
      din >> name >> position >> team >> g >> att >> attg >> cmp >> pct >> yds >> ydsg >> lng >> td >> inte >> sck >> sckyl >> rating;

      Node *temp = new Node(name, position, team, g, att, attg, cmp, pct, yds, ydsg, lng, td, inte, sck, sckyl, rating);
      temp->setNext(head);
      head = temp;
   }

   din.close();
   head->print();
   return true;
}

//----------------------------------------------
// setNext method
//----------------------------------------------
void Node::setNext(Node* next)
{
   Next = next;
}

//----------------------------------------------
// Print method
//----------------------------------------------
void Node::print() const
{
   cout << Name << "    " << Position << "    " << Team << "    " << G << "    " << Att << "    " << AttG << "    "
        << Cmp << "    " << Pct << "    " << Yds << "    " << YdsG << "    " << Lng << "    " << TD << "    " << Int << "    "
        << Sck << "    " << SckYL << "    " << Rating;
   if (Next != NULL)
      Next->print();
}

//----------------------------------------------
// Main program
//----------------------------------------------

int main()
{
   Node list;
   if (list.readData())
      cout << "Success" << endl;
   else
      cout << "Fail" << endl;

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Well, I don't see anything wrong with this code per se.
Are you sure that you're writing the file correctly?

Comment: If you're asking about the txt file, then yes.  If it would help, I can upload the entire program (though it's nearly 200 lines).

Comment: Alright.  I've edited my original post to include the entire program.  Thanks.

Comment: [This](http://csce.uark.edu/~jgauch/2014/S13/hw/QB.txt) is the file I have to read.

Comment: The one with all 16 parameters?

Comment: Yeah, I noticed I'd copied and pasted incorrectly.

Comment: it seems your file is at fault. Everything works with this content: `Hello Bye Team2 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13`

Comment: That's what I was starting to wonder too.  I just now noticed that the file begins with a line of all strings, followed by lines with the actual data.  Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your file you have, `Charlie Batch` and so on.
What do you think will happen when you read it?
Name will become `Charlie`; position will become `Batch`.

This happens because the data is read until a whitespace is met.

http://cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/fstream/?kw=fstream

Comment: Yeah, that seems to be the problem.  Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried priming your loop? Get the first line of the file, then do your while statement. Inside the while statement, create your new node, then get the next line. End the code block for the loop there.

```
// Read data
Node *head = NULL;

  din >> name >> position >> team >> g >> att >> attg >> cmp >> pct >> yds >> ydsg >> lng >> td >> inte >> sck >> sckyl >> rating;

while (!din.eof())
{

  Node *temp = new Node(name, position, team, g, att, attg, cmp, pct, yds, ydsg, lng, td, inte, sck, sckyl, rating);
  temp->setNext(head);
  head = temp;

  din >> name >> position >> team >> g >> att >> attg >> cmp >> pct >> yds >> ydsg >> lng >> td >> inte >> sck >> sckyl >> rating;

}
```

Comment: I've done that, but I'm not sure if it helps.  When I enter the file name and press enter, nothing happens.  If I enter an invalid file name, I am given the error message.  Also, in the main program, I am only calling the readData method with `readData();`.  This seems odd to me, but it seems to be working fine until the program is supposed to move past the `// Read data` line.

Comment: Disregard the "Also" part of my last comment.  The code above is supposed to be a method, not a function, but I've solved that problem by changing the first line of my above code to `bool Node::readData()`.  I still can't figure out why nothing happens, though.  Thanks again.

Comment: What is stored in each variable if you put in a breakpoint right after the first read from the file?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not sure how to set a breakpoint.  Honestly, I've never heard of that before.

Comment: OK, do a cout that prints the 16 variables after the first read. Then, do this line: system("pause"); That will show you what each variable is holding and pause for you to see the results. It will give us a clue as to whether the problem is with the file formatting or with the code.

Comment: I tried doing this, but nothing happened.  For some reason it just can't get past the "filename" input.

Comment: I'm don't have access to a compiler right now. Why do you cast your filename string to a c_str? The infile.open method can take a normal string.

Comment: Just the way I've been taught.